# Annoying ssh workflow

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, svn

I've been using ssh for svn for a while now, but suddenly this strange thing happen

First, running `svn up` would just do, wonderfully.

Later, running `svn up` prompted me for a password, the suggested solution was to do `sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/*` and then executing the update. Not very painful, but not so fun either.

Now, even that won't work. It says:

`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

So the actual way of making this work is:

`exec ssh-agent bash`

`sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/*`

`svn up`

Is there a way I can avoid doing all that stuff ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put this line into your .profile:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

And it'll be taken care of automatically whenever you open a shell.

You could put the ssh-add command in there too, but I recommend doing that manually so that you can keep your private key passphrase-encrypted.

Comment: mm this doesn't work, still asks for the passphrase (which is empty) and after pressing enter it asks for a password :(

Comment: Just to verify you followed my instructions correctly: are you seeing an "Agent PID 12345" message when you start the shell, and does running 'env' show SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID set?  If you aren't, try moving the ssh-agent line from .profile to .bashrc: maybe your terminal isn't a login shell.

Comment: I put that on my .profile and I'm seeing the Agent PID ### stuff. I have both variables you mention defined.

Comment: Then check the output of 'ssh-add -l' and make sure the relevant key is loaded into the agent.  If it is, and this approach doesn't work while the commands you listed in your question do, then I have no idea what to tell you.

Comment: Why, by the way, are you running the ssh-add command under sudo?  Is there some reason that those keys aren't readable by the user you're running svn under?

Comment: @dfranke ssh-add -l says: "the agent has no identities"

Comment: Which of the alternatives did you choose w.r.t. "You could put the ssh-add command in there too, but I recommend doing that manually so that you can keep your private key passphrase-encrypted"?  And what was the output when that command ran?

Comment: Oh, it's working now. I thought that I didn't have to do the `ssh-add` thing again. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks a lot for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also run svn through apache.  That way you will only need to do the ssh-agent/ssh-add prior to starting apache.

You can then access svn through https.